# How to vary a metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, calculus, variational-calculus

I am doing some GR computations and I want to rescale a metric, this is straightforward becuase I can just rescale the coordinate in question: $x \to x_{\text{rescaled}} = kx$ where k is just some constant.

In particular, I have the 4d Schwarzschild metric

\begin{equation}
ds^2 =g_{ab} dx^a dx^b=  -g(R)dt^2+ g(R)^{-1} dR^2 + R^2d\Omega_2^2.
\end{equation}

If I now let $R \to kR$. I will rescale both $R$ inside of $g(R)$ and $R$ in $dR$.

So, I end up with something like

\begin{equation}
ds_{\text{new}}^2 =g_{ab, \text{new}} dx^a dx^b =  -g(kR)dt^2 + g(kR)^{-1} k^2 dR^2 + k^2 R^2d\Omega_2^2.
\end{equation}

The variation of the metric I guess would now just be the difference between these guys

i.e. $\delta g = g_{ab, \text{new}} - g_{ab}$.

I get
\begin{equation}
\delta g_{rr} =  g(kR)^{-1} k^2 - g(R)^{-1}
\end{equation}

But there should be a way to express this only in terms of $g(R)$ right? Using some properties of derivatives or something.

On the right-hand side of the above expression, I would like $\delta g_{rr} = f(g(R))g_{rr}$ where $f(g(R))$ is some operator that will involve derivatives.

Comment: Set $k = 1 + \epsilon$ and expand.

Comment: Thanks @Javier, is it possible to achieve this without introducing derivatives in k, but only in R? As I understand ityou want me to expand k around k=0 i.e. for very small epsilon?